# How to plot a darker state borderline with googleVis?

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

The state borderline plotted by googleVis is too light for my project.

[image]

I want to do something with the state borderline like this [image]

Is it possible to realize it within the googleVis framework?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720383/5090771)...

Comment: @WhiteHat I don't know how to "translate" the javascript code, but thanks anyways..

Comment: Are you able to share the code used to draw the chart?